# Why does this loop cause a crash if nothing is found in the array

Tags: ios, objective-c, while-loop

I'm totally lost and not sure how to even phrase this question. I have a loop as you can see below. If the `if` statement within the loop proves true `indexPath` is assigned a value, the loop completes (there are 49 objects in the `_samplePicture`s array)and enters the `if (found)` and then loads the found data. If the the condition is not true and nothing is found instead of entering the `if(!found)` the app crashes. I have tried various structures of this current coding scheme. I even removed the loop and entered the `if(!found)` which does what it is supposed to. (ooooodddddddd)

This statement is in the `viewDidLoad` and directly above it (the if statement not the `viewDidLoad`) is an `if` statement that determines the contents of `_samplePictures`.

**It may be useful to know that the images in the array are define like this:**

```
#define IMG_71          [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.jpg"]
```

**the array is structured in this way:**

```
_samplePictures = @[@{@"Image": IMG_71, @"Title" : @"title of item", @"Description" : @"complete description of item"}];

if (fromKitInstructions)
{
    int i = 0;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    found = FALSE;

    while(i <= _samplePictures.count)
    {
        if([_samplePictures[i] objectForKey:@"Title"] == instructionName)
        {
            indexPath  = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            i = 50;
            found = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }

    if(found)
    {
        [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    if(!found)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:instructionName message:@"We are sorry but the Kit ID you searched for could not be found. Press the Back button to return to the Instructions you were viewing." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Say Hello",nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

**Here is the button that gets you into this code:**

```
-(void)goTo:(id)sender
{
    ViewController *goGallery = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    goGallery.setFlag = NO;
    goGallery.fromKitInstructions = YES;
    goGallery.instructionName = instructionName;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:goGallery animated:YES];

}
```

**debugger shows this:**

```
2014-05-30 15:08:37.873 TechBook[3932:60b] [INFO] <HomeViewController: 0xc67bb00> loaded
2014-05-30 15:14:24.268 TechBook[3932:3c03] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForMIMEType:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-05-30 15:14:43.204 TechBook[3932:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 49 beyond bounds [0 .. 48]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01f3d1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cbc8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01ef18b2 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 210
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01fbbf48 -[NSArray objectAtIndexedSubscript:] + 40
    4   TechBook                            0x0000ae3d -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 22381
    5   UIKit                               0x0088e33d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    6   UIKit                               0x0088e5d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    7   UIKit                               0x008a8942 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 778
    8   UIKit                               0x008b58f7 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
    9   UIKit                               0x008b64e9 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    10  UIKit                               0x009f70d1 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    11  UIKit                               0x007de964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01cce82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    13  QuartzCore                          0x001f145a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    14  QuartzCore                          0x001e5244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    15  QuartzCore                          0x001e50b0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0014b7fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0014cb85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0020a5b0 +[CATransaction flush] + 52
    19  UIKit                               0x0076d9bb _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 13095
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01ec677f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01ec610b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01ee31ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01ee29d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x01ee27eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x036d75ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x036d742b GSEventRun + 104
    27  UIKit                               0x0076ff9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    28  TechBook                            0x00003b1d main + 141
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x027ee701 start + 1
    30  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: You probably need `isEqualToString:` I'm place of `==` in the test: `[_samplePictures[i] objectForKey:@"Title"] == instructionName`

Comment: `index 49 beyond bounds [0 .. 48]` -- Seems to me that's your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while(i <= _samplePictures.count)
```

change this to:

```
while(i < _samplePictures.count)
```

The array runs from 0-48, but `_sampePictures.count` returns 49 total objects. So when you hit that last run through your array, the count total is greater than the final index.

Comment: This helped. I matched i to 49 if the Title was found equalToString. Everything works as it should now. This is what happens when you code for hours then at the end of the day you make a small but huge numerical error :) thanks every one.

Answer (score 1):

This style of coding looks complicated and very error prone. There a more more modern constructs that are easier to reason about and less error prone and actually execute faster.

Standard forin loop

```
if (fromKitInstructions) {
  __block NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

  NSInteger index = 0;
  for (NSDictionary *picture in _samplePictures) {
    if ([picture[@"Title"] isEqualToString:instructionName]) {
      indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
      break;
    }
    index++;
  }

  if (indexPath) {
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  } else {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:instructionName
                                message:@"We are sorry but the Kit ID you searched for could not be found. Press the Back button to return to the Instructions you were viewing." 
                               delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Say Hello",nil] show];
  }
}
```

Using blocks

```
if (fromKitInstructions) {
  __block NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

  [_samplePictures enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *picture, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([picture[@"Title"] isEqualToString:instructionName]) {
      indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0];
      *stop = YES;
    }    
  }];  

  if (indexPath) {
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  } else {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:instructionName
                                message:@"We are sorry but the Kit ID you searched for could not be found. Press the Back button to return to the Instructions you were viewing." 
                               delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Say Hello",nil] show];
  }
}
```

---

It's worth noting that you should not do a string comparison with `==` instead you should use `isEqualToString:` or `isEqual:`

---

Another way of writing this that yields slightly less code (less stuff to read) would be

```
if (fromKitInstructions) {
  NSInteger index = [_samplePictures indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(NSDictionary *picture, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [picture[@"Title"] isEqualToString:instructionName];
  }];

  if (NSNotFound == index) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:instructionName
                                message:@"We are sorry but the Kit ID you searched for could not be found. Press the Back button to return to the Instructions you were viewing." 
                               delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Say Hello",nil] show];
  } else {
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually knew to use isEqualToString: been starring at code for far to long. This looks good except [i] in indexPathForRow is an undeclared identifier and using this coding scheme I do not know how to declare it. my understanding of using a for is elementary (i.e. for(int i = 0; condition; increment)) please advise

Comment: Sorry I wrote this in the browser and didn't check it - I've updated it now. You need to keep an additional variable to keep track of the index, which is why I prefer the second form using blocks as you are given the `idx` without having to keep track of it manually

Comment: I got my original way to work by adjusting the value of i and implementing the isEqualToString. However I would like to understand your response better. Get it to operate and understand what makes it less complicated.

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: okay i used your block scheme. I changed i to idx however I get indexPath is not assignable (missing _block type specifier)

Comment: Sorry updated answer to allow the local variable to be modified in the block scope